# Can't run pioneer2dx.world in gazebo, segmentation fault

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run the simulation as it's explained in this tutorial:
http://mobotica.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-gazebo.html

I am a complete beginner in ROS, and I see that I have ros electric installed opposed to the diamondback one in the tutorial. The error I get is:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> "/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.10/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/XMLConfig.cc:77
> : Exception: The world file can not be
> opened, check path and permissions
>
> /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.10/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:205
> : Exception: The XML config file can
> not be loaded, please make sure is a
> correct file
> /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.10/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/XMLConfig.cc:77
> : Exception: The world file can not be
> opened, check path and permissions
>
> Error Loading Gazebo
> /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.10/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:205
> : Exception: The XML config file can
> not be loaded, please make sure is a
> correct file
> /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.10/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/XMLConfig.cc:77
> : Exception: The world file can not be
> opened, check path and permissions
>
> Segmentation fault"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31180/can%27t-run-pioneer2dx.world-in-gazebo,-segmentation-fault/) by [MatijaB](https://answers.ros.org/users/2121/matijab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MatijaB](https://answers.ros.org/users/2121/matijab/) on 2012-04-04**:
@IvanThe .world file I used is from here - http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/wiki/Gazebo:Tutorials:pioneer2dx_moving
I placed it in my ros_workspace and I'm pretty sure I put the path in correctly.

**Comment by [MatijaB](https://answers.ros.org/users/2121/matijab/) on 2012-04-04**:
I used the commands:
cd /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/bin
./gazebo /home//ros_workspace/pioneer2dx.world

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-04-05**:
Try the following command `rosrun gazebo gazebo $( rospack find gazebo )/gazebo/share/gazebo/worlds/pioneer2dx.world`. That's the pioneer2dx world file that is shipped with Gazebo and should work.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-08-03**:
@MatijaB As mentioned by @Timo Röhling and @Ivan Rojas Jofre, I also think that the path is the problem - gazebo surely works nicely and pioneer2dx.world is a well written file

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-08-03**:
@MatijaB To avoid confusion, you can also download the pioneer2dx.world file from this location - http://ubuntuone.com/5pWIiUyo1mhrY2PHP4I86C

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-08-03**:
@MatijaB Also, the permission (sudo) may be an issue ! So, it will either be (1) path or (2) permission (sudo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Might be simpler to go the [ros](http://ros.org) route at first, we maintain a [ros-ified version of gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo).  All the relevant documentations, instructions for installation and tutorials are on ros.org.

Let us know if you have any question about any of these particular projects.

On a side note, if you are interested in inner workings of gazebo, and want the latest and greatest or hack on the sources, please visit [gazebosim.org](http://gazebosim.org), start with [these tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials).  If desired, you can find [the gazebo repository on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/).

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-08-03**:
@hsu Yo ! ...... but that may be a bit steeper learning curve for the newbie ! ..... I would say, for a newbie - stick to ROS and say about 3-4 weeks later check out gazebosim.org ! ...

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-03**:
@Arkapravo  Thanks, I edited my post to reflect your suggestion :)

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-08-03**:
@hsu Cheers to that !!! :-)